# Сохранение уровней в PlayerPrefs и загрузка их по индексу сцены Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, save

Друзья, привет. Нужна помощь, в игре у меня 3 уровня, не могу найти ошибку в коде, но после прохождения первого уровня, становятся доступны сразу все 3, а должны бы по очереди. Сохраняю всё в реестр и вытаскиваю, как уже понятно через PlayerPrefs :) В меню у меня есть 3 кнопки, и на контроллере уровней висит массив из этих самых кнопок. Но прилетает ошибка после того, как автоматически загружаются сохранённые данные о том, что уровень пройден, и должен открыться второй уровень. Код ниже, спасибо. Кстати, сама ошибка: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
LevelManager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Data/LevelManager.cs:24) И хотелось бы дополнить, уровни у меня в Build Settings идут не подряд, а в таком порядке Lvl1, Lvl1Boss, Lvl2, Lvl2Boss, Lvl3.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    int levelUnLock;
    public Button[] buttons;
    public GameObject loadingScreen;

    void Start()
    {
        levelUnLock = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levels", 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < levelUnLock; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = true;
        }
    }

    public void loadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);

        GameObject gameObj = GameObject.Find("AudioSource");
        AudioSource audio = gameObj.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audio.Stop();

        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как происходит сохранение уровней?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ошибке написано, что индекс выходит за пределы массива. Это связано с тем, что вы изменили количество кнопок, а число осталось. Вы можете стереть его с помощью `PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(string key)`. Во время разработки можете вызывать `DeleteKey` из метода `Start`.

```
PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("level");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.